# Best SOCKS proxy server for Linux

Tags: proxy

I want to setup a SOCKS proxy server on linux, any recommendations?

I currently use SS5 and want to know if there are any better alternatives.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno whether it's the best one or not, but I can mention [DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/SOCKS/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need, but the good old [Squid](http://squid-cache.org/) can do almost anything.

Comment: It's in no way a SOCKS proxy, actually.

Comment: @poige actually, it can (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Socks) but it's not really the best fit for a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Better? sure, try Zeus's ZXTM, way better but tens of thousands of dollars per license - could you try narrowing down your requirements please.

Comment: I simply need a socks 5 proxy server that would sit on one physical server with about 30 ips and proxy traffic from traffic from other servers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend SSH as well, mainly because of the strong crypto and maturity of the code. Here is the command I use:

ssh -p 22 -C2qTnN -D 8080 user@remote-ssh-server.net

Comment: You don't actually want a ssh server to do socks on something like a gateway router because of the added issues. A dedicated socks server is alot better