# Is it possible to create ssh socks server with authentication required?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, socks

I was looking at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/165505/best-socks-proxy-server-for-linux) question while I was trying to find a good socks server for linux that would be easy to configure.

The following command works fine:

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```

I was wondering, though, if it is possible to have some kind of authentication required for the socks proxy to work - i.e. an existing unix user & correct password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with OpenSSH. You will need to use a Socks5 proxy server like [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/).

Comment: I was left under the same impression. A follow up question - do you by any chance have a sample configuration of the dante authentication? I saw https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/config/auth_username.html but I can't figure out how to create users and where does Dante read them from?